How to find a Cell, Row and Column position, relative to its Parent Range?
Considering the following simplified Function:
Private Function FindJimmy(rngMyRange As Range) As Long
Dim oneCell As Range
rngMyRange.cells(2,2) =  "Jimmy"
    For Each oneCell In rngMyRange
        If oneCell.Value = "Jimmy" Then
            Debug.Print oneCell.Row, oneCell.Column
            FindJimmy = oneCell.Row
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next oneCell
FindJimmy = 0
End Function 

The Debug.Print oneCell.Row, oneCell.Column  will print the absolute row and column number relative to the whole worksheet containing  rngMyRange.
Since rngMyRange start at absolute Cells(5,5), the relative value of the found cell would then be 2,2 if the absolute cell address is found at (6,6).
If a range is pass to the function, there should be a simple way of finding the relative address of the found cell instead of the absolute address.
The Question: How to determine the Row and Column position of oneCell relative to rngMyRange ?

Consider the difference between rngMyRange.Row, rngMyRange.Column and oneCell.Row, oneCell.Column?

@BigBen - Yes, I do realize that both are absolute values pertaining to the whole worksheet. Intuitively, if considering the line rngMyRange.cells(2,2) =  "Jimmy" explicitly specify (2,2) the relative address, then one can posit that, in the same "philosophy" thinking, there should be a simple way of getting the cell object address relative to its container. shouldn't it?

Yes, it's simple algebra. Difference of row / column position.

Since VBA apparently do not offer a ready function to offer the information, here is a proposed solution:
Private Function RelativeRow(rngMyRange As Range, strQuery As String) As Long
Dim oneCell As Range
Dim FirstRow As Long, FirstCol As Long
FirstRow = rngMyRange.Row: FirstCol = rngMyRange.Column
    For Each oneCell In rngMyRange
        If oneCell.Value = strQuery Then
            Debug.Print oneCell.Row, oneCell.Column
            RelativeRow = oneCell.Row - FirstRow + 1
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next oneCell
RelativeRow = 0
End Function


I assume oneCell will always be below and to the right of rngMyRange, yes?
Math saves the day:
JimmyRow = (oneCell.Row - rngMyRange.Row) + 1
JimmyColumn = (oneCell.Column - rngMyRange.Column) + 1

With the row and column as separate variables, you can use and manipulate that however you want to accomplish your purposes.

If you need the relative reference instead of absolute, you can get the output of Address in R1C1 Notation and get the relative row number:

3 examples, where UDF returns row relative number and it returns 0 if Jimmy is not found.
Function findJimmy(ByVal targetRange As Range) As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim jimmyAddress As String

For Each rng In targetRange.Cells
    If rng.Value = "Jimmy" Then
        'get relative address in R1C1
        jimmyAddress = rng.Address(False, False, xlR1C1, False, targetRange.Cells(1, 1))
        
        'get row part only
        jimmyAddress = Split(jimmyAddress, "C")(0)
        
        'if previous output is just 'R' means same row than top left cell
        If jimmyAddress = "R" Then
            findJimmy = 1
        Else
            findJimmy = 1 + Split(Split(jimmyAddress, "[")(1), "]")(0)
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
Next rng

'no jimmy
findJimmy = 0
End Function

The main advantage of this approach is that the code itself will handle the relative position, it does not matter where the source is located. You don't need to adjust manually substracting 2 or whatever
